# How to test emergency broadcasts?

Tags: 8.1-oreo, emergency-calls, cell-broadcast

I want to test the emergency broadcast notifications (those for extreme weather and similar) to make absolutely sure that they work and everything is set up correctly.

How can I do this? Google only tells me how to disable them, when test broadcast for the entire USA happened in the past or gives me an app that produces fake alerts that don't use the builtin system.

<sub>Fairphone 2, LineageOS 18.1 (Android 8.1), rooted and XPosed installed with Magisk</sub>

Comment: The tags were just guesses, I found nothing more fitting. Please correct them if you have a better idea.

Comment: I guess with the Corona stuff, either my emergency broadcast notifications are **not** working or whoever is responsible to create these broadcasts didn't do their job very well.